# Listview Filtering

Tags: android, mysql, listview

This is my code with my custom adapter,I have listview populated with the mysql data but doing searching in edittext shows zero result.

```
        lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViews);
        search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);


        items=new ArrayList<Client_information>();
        adapter=new Client_storeAdapter(getApplicationContext(),items);

        lst.setAdapter(adapter);

        Thread thread=new Thread(doInBackground);
        thread.start();

        search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
        });

 }
 Runnable doInBackground=new Runnable()
 {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        items = Client_service.getAllRadioclient(myValue);
        runOnUiThread(runOnUi);
    }

 };

 Runnable runOnUi=new Runnable()
 {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        for(Client_information radioitems:items)
        {
            adapter.add(radioitems);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 };
```

}
This is my code with my custom adapter,I have listview populated with the mysql data but doing searching in edittext shows zero result.

Comment: Try putting up a SOP line inside the onTextChanged listener to ensure that your code reaches that point

Comment: didn't get your answer.

Comment: Are you sure that your code reached the onTextChanged method? Try printing something in that method using a system.out.println in that method. It will display it in log cat.

Comment: yes it is reaching the onTextChanged method.